# conemu do not group tabs

Tags: tabs, conemu

I see that recent conemu versions display tasks as submenus of groups - is there a way to turn this off and get back to old behavior, that is, clicking a task name starts it immediately instead of showing submenu?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may see that issue was accepted:
http://code.google.com/p/conemu-maximus5/issues/detail?id=1234

As temporary workaround you may use Right Click on task if you are using mouse.

Comment: Issue fixed in the build 130923.